# Notify ListView of a change in an item

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` with `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource`.  How do I make sure that the list view reacts to changes in individual collection items?

Basically, I want a list view with alternating backgrounds for items.  When an item is inserted in the middle of the list, the background needs to be flipped for everything after it.  The only way I found was by **replacing** each affected item in the collection, which on iOS translates into ugly visual effects.  I would like to just redraw the background.

Simply binding the background property does not work: there is no notification on the property change.

Maybe there is a way to send a custom notification to all/some visible rows in the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, then `MyClass` needs to implement [INotifiyPropertyChanged](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) in order to notify the bound UI that it's properties have changed.

Comment: To clarify -- by `MyClass` you mean the class of the item in the `ObservableCollection` (i.e., `ItemsSource = ObservableCollection<MyClass>`)?  Also -- what should the implementation of `INotifiyPropertyChanged` do?

Comment: yes, whatever class is contained in the ObservableCollection.  INotifyPropertyChanged is documented in the linked article, and in 1000s of other places in SO and all over the web, so I'm not going to give another full explanation here.  Basically, it fires a PropertyChanged event whenever a property on your class is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I'm thinking right now is using MessagingCenter. Set a message when the collection change and on the message process do the background change depending on the actual row the item is.

This Message should be implemented on the ViewCell (or whatever cell) you are using to present the data to the user. So you can do something like this:

```
public MyViewCell()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this as object, "UpdateBackground", (obj) => 
    { 
        //Your logic to change background here
    });
}
```

And when your collection changes (this on your controller, ViewModel or code behind) send the message to execute this code

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this as object, "UpdateBackground");
```

My only concern is that if you subscribe a lot of message (1 ViewCell per item) is going to impact the memory but I hope this leads to a better option.

The other thing I can suggest is to check UITableView (iOS) and ListView (on Android) and see if you can achieve this using Custom Renderers

Best regards

**EDIT:**
Also you can use DataTemplateSelector to detect (depending of the Item bind to the view) which ItemTemplate use. I know if the collection changes the DataTemplateSelector redraws or somehow calls back a "refresh" into the ListView and present new data. If it does, is a better approach that what I told you before. I will try it tomorrow just for fun.